# Compound Interest Formula help in Swift xCode

Tags: swift, xcode6, formula

Balance(Y)   =   P(1 + r)^Y   +   c[ ((1 + r)^Y + 1 - (1 + r)) / r ]

Can some of you formula experts help me code this in Apple's Swift please. I tried but some math is off and I got in endless loop also.  Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do the required behavior?

```
func balance(P:Double, r:Double, c:Double, Y:Double) -> Double {
    var bal:Double
    bal = pow(P*(1+r),Y) + c * (pow(1+r, Y+1) - (1 + r))/r
    return bal
}
```

called like var balance = balance(1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 7.0)

oops forgot my return type.

Comment: swift giving an error on 4th line:    'Double' is not convertible to '()'    Do you have swift also?  and second part is raised to the Y+1  so need (Y+1) ?

Comment: forgot return type, edited

Comment: also the Y+1 thing wasnt clear from the original post. I updated my code to raise to Y+1.

Comment: Will How can I pate in nicely formatted code here? I fixed the equation a little. thx  Mike  I will delete this when I get code nicely pasted in.

Comment: func balance(P:Double, r:Double, c:Double, Y:Double) -> Double {
            var bal:Double
            bal = P*pow((1+r),Y) + c * ( (pow((1+r),(Y+1)) - (1 + r))/r)
            return bal
        }
        
        var fv:Double = balance(P, r, c, Y)